# Apache tomcat shutdown and start with ant build

Tags: ant

how to write a target in ant build to shutdown and start apache tomcat 7.0.42. this is used at the time deployment. We need to stop tomcat server at the time of deployment and start the server once the files were deployed over there.

Answer (score 0):

You could execute tomcat stop/start scripts in an Ant target using the [Exec Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html).

On linux, if the script you are executing has a shebang and has executable permission set, then the exec attribute of the task can be set to the script file. If not, or on Windows, the exec attribute can be set to an interpreter (cmd, bash, ...).

Comment: I am running tomcat server in linux machine. Will execute target work there

Comment: May know how to run commant "/shutdown.sh" in linux with the folder 10.0.15.32:/home/Deploymenttest/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin folder

Comment: I tried with this code, <target name="stop">
              <exec executable="sh" >
                <arg value="-c" />
                <arg value='${tomcat.bin}/shutdown.sh -Xms128M -Xmx512M' />
            </exec>
   </target> it returns error like this "Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: `/bin/sh` ? `/bin/bash` ?

Comment: I have tried with both /bin/sh and /bin/bash. same issue occurs